# Is there a way to programmatically convert other Xaml elements to path elements?

Tags: wpf, path, expression-blend, shapes

In Blend, it is possible to convert certain Xaml elements to Path, using Object->Path->Convert to Path option.

Is there some API to do the same programmatically, in a WPF application?

Thanks

Comment: +1 from way back. I am actually using DotPeek to see how Expression Blend does this, so will let you know if there is publicly exposed way (or if I can make one) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having dived into the source-code of Expression Blend with DotPeek (for research purposes of course), I can say that the *Convert to Path* API is not exposed in a useful way.

Internally it uses a number of private methods to convert RichTextBox content, TextBlocks, TextBoxes and simply geometry.

The only external method is in Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Geometry:

```
public static PathGeometry[] ConvertToPathGeometries(SceneElement element)
```

But the parameter `SceneElement` is a type used only within Expression blend and has a huge number of dependencies. There appears no easy way to create SceneElements for your own Silverlight objects outside of Expression Blend. You could probably execute the functionality as a Blend add-in but I don't see you getting it working in a stand-alone application.

*It was an interesting exercise, but unsuccessful. Sorry.*